# Reduce method to access an element

Tags: javascript, reduce

`Data:`

```
const movies = [{
    actor: "John, Tim, Annie, Tony",
    boxOffice: "$434,038,008",
    language: "English",
    title: "Toy Story 4",
 }]
```

> Question: To Return the name of the movie with the highest box office. amount.

My code:

```
const convertBoxOfficeToNumber = (boxOffice) => Number(boxOffice.replace('$', "").replaceAll('.', ''))

const getBiggestBoxOfficeMovie = (movies) => movies.reduce((accumulator, currentMovie) => Math.max(accumulator, convertBoxOfficeToNumber(currentMovie.boxOffice)), null)
```

I used a helper function to convert the `boxOffice` value to remove the dollar sign, and commas and convert to the Number type and then used reduce method to get the max value of `boxOffice` amount

My question: how do I return the title of the movie?

PS: Mandatory to use the `reduce` method to get the max value of `boxOffice`

Answer (score 1):

The accumulator should probably be the largest movie object found so far - in which case calling `Math.max` on it doesn't make sense. After converting the property to a sensible number, compare it against the same property in the accumulator (if one exists), and if the new value is greater, return the new value - otherwise, return the old value.

```js
const movies = [
  { actor: "John, Tim, Annie, Tony", boxOffice: "$434,038,008", language: "English", title: "Toy Story 4", },
  { actor: "John, Tim, Annie, Tony", boxOffice: "$234,038,008", language: "English", title: "Toy Story 5", },
  { actor: "John, Tim, Annie, Tony", boxOffice: "$634,038,008", language: "English", title: "Toy Story 6", }
];

const convertBoxOfficeToNumber =({ boxOffice }) => Number(boxOffice.replace('$',"").replaceAll('.',''))
                                                         
const getBiggestBoxOfficeMovie = (movies) => {
  const biggestMovie = movies.reduce((biggestMovieSoFar, currentMovie) => {
    const biggestSoFarValue = biggestMovieSoFar ? convertBoxOfficeToNumber(biggestMovieSoFar) : 0;
    const currentMovieValue = convertBoxOfficeToNumber(currentMovie);
    return biggestSoFarValue > currentMovieValue ? biggestMovieSoFar : currentMovie;
  }, null);
  return biggestMovie?.title;
};
console.log(getBiggestBoxOfficeMovie(movies));
```

If you can always count on the array not being empty, it gets simpler:

```js
const movies = [
  { actor: "John, Tim, Annie, Tony", boxOffice: "$434,038,008", language: "English", title: "Toy Story 4", },
  { actor: "John, Tim, Annie, Tony", boxOffice: "$234,038,008", language: "English", title: "Toy Story 5", },
  { actor: "John, Tim, Annie, Tony", boxOffice: "$634,038,008", language: "English", title: "Toy Story 6", }
];

const convertBoxOfficeToNumber =({ boxOffice }) => Number(boxOffice.replace('$',"").replaceAll('.',''))
                                                         
const getBiggestBoxOfficeMovie = (movies) => {
  const biggestMovie = movies.reduce((biggestMovieSoFar, currentMovie) => {
    const biggestSoFarValue = convertBoxOfficeToNumber(biggestMovieSoFar);
    const currentMovieValue = convertBoxOfficeToNumber(currentMovie);
    return biggestSoFarValue > currentMovieValue ? biggestMovieSoFar : currentMovie;
  });
  return biggestMovie.title;
};
console.log(getBiggestBoxOfficeMovie(movies));
```

or if you wanted

```js
const movies = [
  { actor: "John, Tim, Annie, Tony", boxOffice: "$434,038,008", language: "English", title: "Toy Story 4", },
  { actor: "John, Tim, Annie, Tony", boxOffice: "$234,038,008", language: "English", title: "Toy Story 5", },
  { actor: "John, Tim, Annie, Tony", boxOffice: "$634,038,008", language: "English", title: "Toy Story 6", }
];

const convertBoxOfficeToNumber =({ boxOffice }) => Number(boxOffice.replace('$',"").replaceAll('.',''))
                                                         
const getBiggestBoxOfficeMovie = (movies) => {
  const biggestMovie = movies.reduce((biggestMovieSoFar, currentMovie) =>
    convertBoxOfficeToNumber(biggestMovieSoFar) > convertBoxOfficeToNumber(currentMovie)
      ? biggestMovieSoFar
      : currentMovie
  );
  return biggestMovie.title;
};
console.log(getBiggestBoxOfficeMovie(movies));
```